# How to specify to do a function in a specific area only, in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select, hover

I have this jQuery snippet:

```
$(function() {
        $("ul > li").hover(function() {
          $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'fast');
        });
    });
```

This opens every `<ul>` what's inside in another `<ul>`, but I want to make this only for
:

`<div id="header"></div>`

**EDIT**

Here is the structure, I modified it a bit, originally I want to add it to my `header id` but that's better I think:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>List item 1 
        <ul>
            <li>Sub List Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub List Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub List Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

*Please don't eat me if the question is stupid I'm really really new in jQuery :)*

Comment: Okay, what does your current selector *do*, and what do you *want it to do instead*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
$("ul > li")
```

To

```
$("#header ul > li")
```

This is going to limit the elements for the ones inside the `header` div.

Comment: Hmm I was adding #navigation to the `ul` that's why didn't worked, if I add to a parent div then it works. thanks! And I think if I replace `ul` with `#navigation` then will work just how I want it :D

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there's only one `ul` within the `#navigation` div:

```
$('#navigation ul > li').hover( /* rest of jQuery function */ );
```

The selector used, above, selects only `li` elements that are direct descendants of a ul that is itself a descendant of an element of `id="navigation"`.

You could, also, simply apply an id *to* the `ul`, for example `id="navList"` and then use:

```
$('#navList > li').hover( /* rest of jQuery function */ );
```

---

**Edited** following OP's changed question/posted (x)html.

Given the following mark up:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>List item 1 
        <ul>
            <li>Sub List Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub List Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub List Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And assuming that he wants the user to hover over the `li` elements to reveal that `li`s child `ul`:

```
$('#navigation > li').hover(
// selects any li that's a direct descendant of the ul with id="navigation"
    function() {
        $('ul', this).stop(true,true).animate({opacity:'toggle'},fast);
        // looks for 'ul' elements inside the currently-selected 'this' object.
        // have a look at the jQuery api for more information on this approach: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
    }
);
```

Please note that I haven't tested the function you're trying to apply, I take it on trust that you've already got it working.

Comment: And there should I use this? Before the snippet or inside of it? Just because the `.hover`

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the original `$('ul > ul')` with the modified selector above, and see what works. I'm not entirely sure, but have you edited your question since I originally answered? I'm convinced that when I first read it the selector was `$("ul ul")`?

Comment: No I did not edited the content of it, only the title but before you answered to my question :)

Comment: Oh, okay. It's worth pointing out that `$('ul > ul')` shouldn't match anything, a `ul` can't be a direct descendant of a `ul`; the child `ul` should be enclosed by a `li` element (only `li` is a legitimate/valid child of list elements (`ul` and `ol`) reference: [W3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html#ul).

Comment: Edited my answer please check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

David is correct, or add a class or ID to your `<UL>` and target it directly: `$('ul#ul-id').hover( /* .... */ );`

Comment: lol I think you changed it while I was typing. Plus my rep is below 100 so I have to keep trying until 3 minutes are up.... bogosity

Comment: Yeah, I must confess that I edited my answer then saw new answers, so...yup =) Only another seven up-votes to go and the shackles come off =)

Answer (score 1):

BrunoLM provides a good answer, just change the jQuery selector to `#header ul > li`. jQuery understands CSS.

But a good thing to know about in jQuery is that you can provide **[a context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** for your jQuery selector. Normally a jQuery selector looks in the entire DOM. If you want to narrow this or have it look somewhere else provide a context. To look for `this` in a `context` use the form:

```
$(this, context)
```

In your specific case this would be:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul > li", "#header").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Now, the context works by internally applying **[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**, so the above is synonymous to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").find("ul > li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'fast');
    });
});
```

The above two methods are very useful if you can't apply CSS to the problem... Let's say you're creating a DOM element on the fly, and you want to use jQuery within that element.